# ¿Cómo quedaría esta consulta si la quiero convertir a linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select p.id_Permiso, p.id_TiposP, p.id_Empleado, p.id_Otorgante, p.id_Estatus, p.dia_Permiso, p.descripcion from Permisos as p join Empleados as e on (e.id_Empleado = p.id_Empleado) join Jerarquia as j on (e.id_Empleado = j.id_Empleado) where j.id_Area = any (Select id_Area from Jerarquia where id_Empleado = 1 and id_Estatus = 1) and e.id_Turno = 1 and e.id_Estatus = 1 and j.id_Estatus = 1
```

Quiero convertirla a linq, sin embargo no tengo muy claro el como aplicar el Any que tengo en sql a Linq, mi consulta la tengo así hasta ahora:

```
var permisos = (from p in dbT.Permisos
                join e in dbT.Empleados on p.id_Empleado equals e.id_Empleado
                join j in dbT.Jerarquia on e.id_Empleado equals j.id_Empleado
                where e.id_Turno == 1 && e.id_Estatus == 1 && j.id_Estatus == 1
                select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de todo no fue necesario usar el Any, lo solucioné separando la consulta, ya que tengo solo dos casos posibles en mi programa:

1- Un usuario puede tener todas las áreas y ver todos los registros sin restricción alguna

2- Un usuario puede tener solo una área y solo puede ver registros activos

Por lo que decidí validar por medio del tipo de usuario, siendo así que para el primer caso:

```
var permisos = db.Permisos.Include(p => p.Empleados).Include(p => p.Empleados1).Include(p => p.Estatus).Include(p => p.Tipo_Permiso);
    
return View(permisos.ToList());
```

Y para el segundo:

```
var aux = (from j in db.Jerarquia
           where j.id_Empleado == hel.id_Empleado
           select j).FirstOrDefault();

var permisos = (from p in dbT.Permisos
                join e in dbT.Empleados on p.id_Empleado equals e.id_Empleado
                join j in dbT.Jerarquia on e.id_Empleado equals j.id_Empleado
                where e.id_Turno == hel.id_Turno && e.id_Estatus == 1 && j.id_Estatus == 1 && j.id_Area == aux.id_Area
                select p).AsQueryable<Permisos>();

return View(permisos.ToList());
```

Siendo la variable "hel" otra variable aparte que contiene la información del empleado, con la cual extraigo la "Jerarquía" o "Área" a la que pertenece.